# Why does google add space after my character

Tags: meta-tags, googlebot

On my page i have set meta tag for description, which then use google. It's all normal. But from some reason google add space after one character. Here is my meta description:

```
 Igraj brezplačne online igre! Izbiraj med več kot 6.000 igrami! Vsak dan dodajamo nove igre! Igraj zdaj!
```

Yes it's not in english, but that's normal :D
And her is how google shows it:

```
 Igraj brezplač ne online igre! Izbiraj med več kot 6.000 igrami! Vsak dan dodajamo nove igre! Igraj zdaj!
```

The problem is first 'č' character google ads space after it. Check google description of it:
https://www.google.si/search?q=bringler&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

I have no idea why does it do it. And the funny part is that after second one all is ok, so no space added.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content (the actual one in the `meta`-`description`, not the one in your question) contains a hidden control character: U+008D REVERSE LINE FEED

You can see it if you analyze the characters in the string, e.g. with Rishida’s String analyser: [analyze "brezplačne"](http://rishida.net/tools/analysestring/index.php?list=brezpla%C4%8D%C2%8Dne)

If you copy the string directly from your `meta`-`description` and search for it in Google, it converts it to `brezplaÄ Â ne`.

So, replace the string "`brezplačne`" (note that Stack Overflow removes this hidden character, so these strings are actually the same here) in your content with "`brezplačne`" and you should be fine (when Google visits your page again, in some time).

Comment: Ok thanks I did it, lets see if it helps. Thank u very much. U have any idea how did it get there?

Comment: @gabrjan: Did you copy&paste the word from somewhere? Maybe the control character was included there.

Comment: I didn't do it but those meta tags added somebody else. How can i check if it's ok now?

Comment: Copy the relevant word(s) and paste them into the [String analyser](http://rishida.net/tools/analysestring/index.php). If you only the see the visible characters, you are fine.